# Как заполняется массив в ArrayList Java

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, динамические-массивы

Суть задачи состоит в создании ArrayList и добавлении в него обычных массивов, которые затем необходимо заполнить данными. Появился такой вопрос, каким образом заполняются массивы в ArrayList?
Конкретно непонятна запись во внутреннем цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j<nums.get(i).length; j++ )
       {
           nums.get(i)[j] = i;
       }
    }
```

Здесь представлен весь код метода:

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> createList()
    {
        ArrayList<int[]> nums = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        nums.add(new int[5]);
        nums.add(new int[2]);
        nums.add(new int[4]);
        nums.add(new int[7]);
        nums.add(new int[0]);
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<nums.get(i).length; j++ )
            {
                nums.get(i)[j] = i;
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `get(i)` объекта `nums` типа `ArrayList<int[]>` возвращает `i`-ый элемент списка `nums`, коим является объект типа `int[]` – массив целых чисел. Далее, во внутреннем цикле этот массив инициализируется значениями.

Comment: `nums.get(i)[j] = i;` получается в данной записи `get(i)` получает `int[]` из ArrayList, а по значению `[j]` полученный массив заполняется данными(присваивается значение), я верно понимаю?

Comment: Метод `get(i)` не **получает**, а **возвращает** `int[]` (получает он `i`). Индекс `j` указывает какому элементу полученного массива `int[]` присвоить значение `i`.